# Why does Bluetooth Audio has worse audio quality than cable, when the signal is digital

Tags: headphones

It is often said that Bluetooth Audio devices have worse audio quality, then when you connect your f.e. headphones to your phone with a cable.

I don't quite understand why, as the music is stored digitally, and then only converted via a DAC.

If you send this data via bluetooth and the headphones have a good DAC, the audio quality should be the same, right?

Is it limited by the bandwidth of bluetooth?

Comment: Hi. Could share your sources, please?

Comment: I don't directly have sources. At it is just daily talk. But about everyone is saying that. So maybe my question is more to get a source which explains why

Comment: Considering that the audio chain can have a lot of links, and most of them can be weak, the Bluetooth channel is not necessary the weakest of them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the bandwidth which requires a compressed format, but the bandwidth is indirectly determined by the amount of energy allowed to allocate to transmission. Since a smartphone is not supposed to ask for a charger after supplying 30 minutes of music via bluetooth to a pair of earphones (and the hardware manufacturers have pretty tight rules here), this is not going to change without a wholly new encoding scheme.

An introduction is in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_(A2DP)).